# Jenkins got error while getting the source from Team Foundation Server

Tags: java, ios, jenkins, tfs

Jenkins got error while getting the source from Team Foundation Server

> Building in workspace \custom_workspace
>   [custom_workspace] $ tf workspaces -format:brief
>   -server:http://:8080/tfs/********

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tf" (in directory "
<WorkspacePath>\custom_workspace"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:816)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:382)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TfTool.execute(TfTool.java:99)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.execute(Server.java:120)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Workspaces.getListFromServer(Workspaces.java:38)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Workspaces.populateMapFromServer(Workspaces.java:50)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Workspaces.exists(Workspaces.java:76)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.actions.CheckoutAction.checkout(CheckoutAction.java:36)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.checkout(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:176)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1280)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:288)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 19 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by giving the absolute path(C:\TEE-CLC-12.0.2\tf.exe) in Team foundation server in Jenkins system configuration.